# Is there a way to auto refresh a variable on a php code without reloading the page?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP file with a form and a variable that gets the total numbers of posts from mySQL.

$number shows the result of the SQL query. The total number is useful to me because I use a form and I submit the number also. In the period that I complete the form, the number may change at anytime because a user has submitted a new post during this period. That means the number I send is wrong.

I thought of a solution that reloads a part of the php code and it will work great for me.
I am not a PHP specialist for very advanced solutions, so any ideas and examples are welcome.

Comment: Can you expand on the reason why you need to submit the value of `$number` with your form?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for an [AJAX based solution](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) in PHP.

## Update

Here is *sample* HTML page making AJAX based call to a php script every 10 sec to get refreshed value for your variable. I have intentionally not used jquery etc to demonstrate how AJAX calls are made from a HTML page, this might require some tuning though.

```
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript">
var refresh = 10000; // 10 sec; change it if you want
function Ajax(){
    var xmlHttp;
    try{    
       xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }
    catch (e){
       try{
          xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
       }
       catch (e){
          try{
             xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch (e){
             alert("No AJAX!?");
             return false;
          }
      }
  }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        // here you assign fetched value to your input field
        document.myForm.myVar.value = xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()', refresh);
     }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET","http://example.com/script_that_refreshes_var.php",true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload=function() {
    setTimeout('Ajax()', refresh);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="myVar" value="<?php echo $myVarInitialVal;?>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, a textbox contains the number. The number is taken from the sql query. If i reload the entire page (and there was a new post in the meantime) the textbox will get the new number. So my question is how can I reload the `echo $number` without reloading the whole page.

Comment: @Rocky: That's the reason I suggested you taking AJAX route. If you make an AJAX call from your page at a set interval then you can refresh that textbox **WITHOUT** refreshing whole page.

Comment: @anubhava oh now I cleared my thought, thank you. Can I make an ajax call without javascript? Because the link you posted is kinda different from what I am looking. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rocky: AJAX means `Asynchronous Javascript and XML` so you must need some kind of Javascript support in your page to use it.

Comment: Rocky, although an AJAX solution is what you actually asked for it's probably not the best solution for your problem.

Comment: @Rocky: I have posted some sample code for you, hope that helps you understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Don't submit the number from the form, determine the number in the code that takes the form data.  Clearly the result of a SQL query is not form data (unless you can describe why your situation requires otherwise).

If this doesn't answer your question, I think we need much more info and some actual code examples in order to help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I am using wordpress and I kinda modified tdomf plugin, if you are aware of it.
Your idea is the ideal but a bit difficult for me because I can't find where is the form that gets the data. I will make again a try and get back to you

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about the Wordpress code base.  Clearly, you are submitting the from SOMEWHERE, but I don't know where that processing occurs.  Perhaps ask on a WordPress forum or ask the plugin author.  You should mention in your question that you are using WordPress and not vanilla PHP.

Comment: Rocky, if the $number is in any way important (i.e. must be correct, must exist, be in a certain range, etc.) you should not rely on the form to do the right thing. Forms are client-side and can easily be altered by an attacker. Never trust data from the client! Also, reloading it on the client means it will eventually be too slow when traffic gets heavy. Best avoid that problem now. Matt's suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply grab the $number on the processing script, instead of sending it via the form. Two users are filling out the form and both hit submit -> processing script always has an accurate count. Otherwise you get into unnecessary AJAX usage.

Comment: Because the processing form of the script i am using is hard coded

Answer (score 0):

What about a Javascript `setTimeout()` loop, calling an AJAX update function that retrieves the updated post count and fills in the appropriate HTML element?  Calling it every 10ish seconds should do it (too often and it will have a tendency to hog slow internet connections).

The exact code will of course depend on the AJAX library used, and the exact page layout.

```
// Javascript
function startUpdate()
{
   AJAX.call("http://path/to/server/script.php", "updateCallback");
}

function updateCallback(value)
{
    document.getElementById('variableDiv').innerHTML = value;
    setTimeout("startUpdate();", 10000);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Well this is interesting. Thank you for that. Do you have any example tutorial ?

Comment: I gave a simple example, you will require some basic Javascript understanding at minimum.